# Capture screen to file or URL like a web cam?

Tags: windows-7, webcam, screen-capture

I see a couple questions like this but they don't really answer my question, and many nights of Google searches haven't turned up any good solutions.

Is there some software I can use to record my screen, either all windows on the desktop or a full screen application hopefully, and then save a JPG file periodically to a folder? Maybe a screen capture program that will automatically save images several times a minute? Or a web cam type software that would fulfill a similar purpose with images or video, but not require plugins such as Java or Flash?

I can take the files that it generates and make my own Javascript enhanced HTML page that refreshes with the newest image, but if that feature is part of the package even better.

I'm using Windows 7 currently, and the goal is to be able to view what my computer is up to remotely, from a simple web browser on another computer or on my smartphone.

Comment: To me screen capturing == camtasia. There may be free/cheaper solutions out there though.

Comment: Try [ActivePresenter](http://atomisystems.com). It allows you to record full motion video or capture series of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found several different programs that will do this after a few seconds of Google Search. My search criteria was

`automatic screen capture`

AutoScreenShot
http://www.theuds.com/download/install_autoscreenshot.exe
[image: AutoScreenShot]

Fergo
[Fergo's Website](http://www.fergonez.net/index.php?lang=en&page=apps&pid=11)
[image: Fergo]

Comment: Sigh... thanks for proving my ineptness in Google :) I guess I kept typing in webcam or screenshot or something, then today I decided I was willing to write an HTML / Javascript solution if I could just get a series of JPGs.

Answer (score 1):

Not free, but you can use SnagIt to perform a screen capture every [x] number of seconds/minutes/hours and have it automatically save to a certain file/folder.

Comment: Did you not see my answer from two hours ago? Posted two free ways.

Comment: I saw it, but wanted to post another solution

Comment: Yea. I use SnagIT every day. It is pretty amazing.

Comment: After checking these out SnagIt is a very good suggestion too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want to accomplish is the equivalent of [VNC: virtual network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) computing, or network remote control. It's pretty simple to set up a [VNC server](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/winvnc.html) on a desktop machine, and you can use a [VNC client](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php) to monitor that computer in a "view only" mode. VNC is a pretty standard network protocol, so you'll need to have the [right network infrastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) in place depending on where you want to view it from.

This also necessitates that you have a VNC client on the computer you wish to view from. If this is not necessarily the case, it is possible to use a [Flash](http://flashlight-vnc.sourceforge.net/) or [Java](http://www.realvnc.com/support/javavncviewer.html) VNC client that is viewable in a browser; you could provide this either on [another server](http://danielwebb.us/software/vnc/) or as an HTTP service on the computer on which you are running the VNC server.